# Error - Bad Row Offset

Tags: php, sql

When getting all values from db table, I get this error on the last result value.

```
Warning: mssql_result() function.mssql-result:
  Bad row offset (32) in C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\mapserver\data\.... on line 38
```

Line 38:

```
$str  = "MyMap_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $row, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")."_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $row, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
```

AND my settings($sql, $con):

```
$con = mssql_connect ("myServer", "myUsername", "myPassword");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM m_group_layer WHERE group_id=\"".$_SESSION["group_id"]."\" ORDER BY display_order";
$rs_group_layer = mssql_query ($sql, $con);
$group_layer_row = mssql_num_rows($rs_group_layer);
```

/* EDIT:

Function:

```
function getLayer($result_set, $row){
    $str  = "MyMap_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $row, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")."_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $row, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
    return "var ".$str.";\n\n";
}
```

Loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<=$group_layer_row; $i++){
    echo getLayer($rs_group_layer, $i);
}
```

*/

Honestly I am not exactly sure what this error this. So if I could get some suggestions first about what typically causes this error, if there is other code that may be responsible I will post as needed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, it seems it'd be easier if you simply set the MySQL connection encoding to the charset you want, instead of converting every single field from SJIS to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I've added the Function and Loop to my question. @deceze, Thanks will implement that, didn't cross my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your main loop, the index variable must start with 0, so if you has 3 lines returning, the last index must be 2.

EDIT:
Change to `for($i=0; $i<$group_layer_row; $i++){`, without `=`, it's a common mistake

Comment: Yes, $i does start from 0. Thanks

Comment: how many lines has the return? and the last $i is...? do a `var_dump($i);` inside the loop and check it.

Comment: loop should return 33 rows. it returns rows 33 --> 2 then gives me this error on the last row

Comment: change to `for($i=0; $i<$group_layer_row; $i++){`, without `=`, it's a common mistake.

Comment: Right. None of my other loops had "=". Thanks alot. Saved me from wasting another day wondering what the hell was going.

Comment: Could you add that to your answer so I can close this question. thanks again.